# How to add a Library as a dependencies in another Library?

Tags: 7, theming

I'm building [D3](https://www.drupal.org/project/d3) libraries to visualize data. The visualizations require the [topojson](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson) Javascript library to manipulate geo shapes.

I want to include the **topojson** javascript library as a dependency in my custom libraries and right now I'm simply including it in the `.info` file for the each library:

`files[js][] = 'js/topojson.v0.min.js'`

However, this adds the **topojson** file to `<head>` section of the page more than once when I have several of these includes.

I want to be able to load the file once and use it in anyone of my D3 libraries. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can add another dependency by using custom module

```
function hook_library() {
  // Library One.
  $libraries['library-1'] = array(
    'title' => 'Library One',
    'website' => 'http://example.com/library-1',
    'version' => '1.2',
    'js' => array(
      drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module') . '/library-1.js' => array(),
    ),
    'css' => array(
      drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module') . '/library-2.css' => array(
        'type' => 'file',
        'media' => 'screen',
      ),
    ),
  );
  // Library Two.
  $libraries['library-2'] = array(
    'title' => 'Library Two',
    'website' => 'http://example.com/library-2',
    'version' => '3.1-beta1',
    'js' => array(
      // JavaScript settings may use the 'data' key.
      array(
        'type' => 'setting',
        'data' => array('library2' => TRUE),
      ),
    ),
    'dependencies' => array(
      // Require jQuery UI core by System module.
      array('system', 'ui'),
      // Require our other library.
      array('my_module', 'library-1'),
      // Require another library.
      array('other_module', 'library-3'),
    ),
  );
  return $libraries;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Adi but is there any way I can do this through the Library API instead?

Comment: yes you can add dependency library